# Can a function with the same name as the contract be declared both as a function and a constructor?

Tags: solidity, constructor

A function with the same name as the contract is normally a constructor and it’s bytecode isn’t included in the resulting contract.

But is there a way to declare a function with the same name as the declared contract name so it’s both a constructor and a function inside the resulting contract with a signature in the function selector bytecode ?

If yes, was it introduced recently or is it part of the language nearly since the beginning ?

Comment: I have doubts [this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/49497/25002) is true. I’m unwilling to spend money on a transaction to check it.

Comment: So test it using the javascript vm in remix.ethereum.org. It won't cost you anything, but it uses the same compiler as you would use to compile smart contracts for the mainnet.

Comment: @user2284570, as mentioned, just use the javascript vm or a testnet. That said, I've just done this and you are correct that the answer is wrong.

Comment: @mafrasi2 do  you also tested with 0.4.24 ?

Comment: yes, that was the version I tested this on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Solidity version [0.4.24](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/releases/tag/v0.4.24) declaring a function with the contracts name as as constructor has been depreciated in favor for `constructor()`

If you are using an older version of Solidity than [0.4.24](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/releases/tag/v0.4.24), you declare the function as `function contractName()`.

Similar to this [answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/7941/5960) constructors are called once, and only once.  They are initiated once a contract has been published, and cannot be called again.

When attempting to use `constructor()` and `function contractName()` in the same contract, it detects two constructors resulting in `DeclarationError: More than one constructor defined.` Meaning that the EVM can detect both as acting constructors and will not compile.  Implying `function contractname()` even when declared as `public` cannot be referred to as a function.

Comment: The answer you linked to says pretty much the opposite, but it's wrong and your answer is correct.

Comment: @O.Privacy do you mean It’s possible since `0.4.24` ?

Comment: @mafrasi2 Thanks for letting me know, linked the wrong one.

Comment: Hello from the future, in version 0.5.0, using `function contractName()` now throws an error.